# How to handle file open from browser NPAPI plugin?

Tags: javascript, c++, plugins, browser, npapi

I need full path to file when file is opened. For example user open *file.txt* but it will be opened with notepad or other. But how to register "hook" from NPAPI plugin to get path to file and prevent opening in other program?

Comment: You need to add more detail; it's not at all clear from your question what you are trying to do. For instance, are you talking about downloaded files? Or are you trying to make a browser plugin that prevents anyone from opening any files on their machine?

Comment: I need a browser plugin to prevent opening some files (like *.txt) on client machine and catch this file path.

Comment: yeah; you can't do that with a browser plugin.  It might be possible to do with an extension.

Answer (score 1):

An NPAPI plugin doesn't sound like it's at all the right technology for what you want to do. Plugins are for running native in the context of a specific web page, whereas it sounds like you just want a local application that's registered with the OS as the handler of certain file types.